# How do you do Access Control in C#?

Tags: c#, acl

How do you do Business-logic level access control in C#?  I started tinkering with a simple system last night that lives inside LINQ objects, but I realized that I'd never seen a particularly clean access control system.  I'd like to know how the gurus do it and see if you spot any holes in my late night toy.

I feel like I'm jumping through some unneeded hoops in order to build a flexible read-only access control object, it just seems like there should be some framework prebuilt widget I'm unaware of.

```
#region Simple Demo
public class SomeObject
{
    public AccessControl AccessControl;
    public SomeObject()
    {
        ConfigureAccessControl();
    }
    private void ConfigureAccessControl()
    {
        AccessControlBuilder acb = new AccessControlBuilder();
        acb.AddRole(UserTypes.Admin, true, true);
        acb.AddRole(UserTypes.Anonymous, true, true);
        acb.AddRole(UserTypes.Owner, true, true);
        acb.AddRole(UserTypes.User, true, true);
        AccessControl = acb.GetAccessControl();
    }
}

public class ObjectFactory
{
    private int _requestingUserId;
    public ObjectFactory(int RequestingUserId)
    {
        _requestingUserId = RequestingUserId;
    }

    public SomeObject GetSomeObject()
    {
        SomeObject sso = new SomeObject();
        if (sso.AccessControl.UserAllowed(_requestingUserId, UserActions.Read))
            return new SomeObject();
        else
            throw new Exception("Unauthorized Access");
    }
}
#endregion

#region AccessControl Code
public class AccessControl
{
    private Hashtable _data = new Hashtable();
    public AccessControl(Hashtable data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }
    public bool UserAllowed(int UserId, UserActions Action)
    {   //Assorted app-specific logic here to determine role.
        //Determine if User is Admin
        //Determine if User is Owner
        //Determine if User is Logged In
        //Determine if User is Anonymous
        //Check read/write for determined role
        return true;
    }
    protected AccessControlSettings Role(UserTypes ut)
    {
        return (AccessControlSettings)_data[ut];
    }
}
public class AccessControlBuilder
{
    private Hashtable _data = new Hashtable();
    public void AddRole(UserTypes ut, bool read, bool write)
    {
        _data.Add(ut, new AccessControlSettings(read, write));
    }
    public AccessControl GetAccessControl()
    {
        return new AccessControl(_data);
    }
}
public enum UserActions
{
    Read,
    Write
}
public enum UserTypes
{
    Admin,
    Owner,
    User,
    Anonymous
}
public class AccessControlSettings
{   //Wraps specific access options so we make them set once in the builder 
    public bool Read { get { return _read; } }
    public bool Write { get { return _write; } }
    private bool _read;
    private bool _write;
    public AccessControlSettings(bool read, bool write)
    {
        _read = read;
        _write = write;
    }
}
#endregion
```